# Survival analysis, one cohort, two classifications

Tags: hypothesis-testing, survival, independence

I'm wondering about this question:

short version:
how to adequately compare the effect of a reclassification of the same subjects on survival

long version:
I have one cancer cohort that was sorted into TNM classes long time ago. The definition of the classes has now been updated and I like to know if, say, class 1 of the old classification has a better/worse survival than class 1 of the updated classification. My problem is that the cohort stays the same, only the sorting into classes changes.

Mini example:
patients 1,2 are in class I_old and patients 3,4 in class II_old, patient 1 stays in class I_new but patient 2 goes to class II_new, patient 3 stays in II_new, patient 4 changes to I_new. If I want to compare the effect of the reclassification in class I, I would have to compare the survival of patients 1 and 2 versus the the survival of patients 1 and 4. So patient 1 is in both of the groups.

I doubt that the standard procedures like logrank test are adequate here. But what can be done? I have a very vague idea about proportional hazards regression with a time varying covariate (namely indicator for "before" and "after" update) or a frailty model but cannot tell at all if I'm going in the right direction.

What do you think?

psj

Comment: Just as a note from what I can gather time varying in this context does not make sense, unless the criteria used to classify individuals in either before or after is time varying itself (in which case I would say you want those characteristics themselves as the covariates not the classification).

Comment: @ Andy W: yes, you're right. Maybe this was why I was uncomfortable with the idea of time varying covariates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll concentrate on your example question: does class 1 of the old classification scheme have a better or worse survival than class 1 of the updated classification scheme?

We can form four mutually exclusive groups of patients:

(a) Patients who weren't in class 1 under either scheme. Clearly, they don't help us answer the question.

(b) Patients who were in class 1 under both schemes. Clearly, they don't help us answer the question either.

(c) Patients who were in class 1 under the old scheme, but aren't in class 1 under the new scheme.

(d) Patients who weren't in class 1 under the old scheme, but are in class 1 under the new scheme.

Compare survival in groups (c) and (d). If survival if better in (c), then class 1 of the old scheme has better survival than class 1 of the new scheme. If survival if better in (d), then class 1 of the new scheme has better survival than class 1 of the old scheme.

Comment: onestop, that's a good idea! Definitively valid with a clear conclusion to be drawn from the results. I don't have the final data until now, but hopefully I will have enough fluctuation between classes. If not, I will have a very small sample size in groups (c) and (d) and inference will be difficult. But that's the best strategy so far... :)